# UserControl: How to set Output Cache duration programmatically?

Tags: asp.net

UserControl: How to set Output Cache duration programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a public property on the UserControl which you could use to change the duration of the cache.

```
 public Double CacheDuration { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CacheDuration));
            Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
```

Then when you add the UserControl, mine is named Cached, you could do this.

```
 var cachedUserControl = new Cached {CacheDuration = 5};
            Page.Controls.Add(cachedUserControl);
```

Comment: Output Cache by default sets Public, not Server ->  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public)

Answer (score 0):

You can sue `Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime DateTime);` for that. Some useful infor here as well [How to enable ASP.NET output caching programmatically](http://blogs.technet.com/stefan_gossner/archive/2005/07/11/407522.aspx).